# How to run a java application created in intelliJ at the command line?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a simple "Hello World" application created in intelliJ using Java.  How do I run the application outside of intelliJ at a terminal command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First result in google: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Run Command Prompt (found under All Programs/Accessories in the Start menu).  Type

`C:\> cd \mywork`

This makes C:\mywork the current directory.

`C:\mywork> dir`

This displays the directory contents.  You should see HelloWorld.java among the files.

`C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin`

This tells the system where to find JDK programs.

`C:\mywork> javac HelloWorld.java`

This runs javac.exe, the compiler.  You should see nothing but the next system prompt...

`C:\mywork> dir`

javac has created the HelloWorld.class file.  You should see HelloWorld.java and HelloWorld.class among the files.

`C:\mywork> java HelloWorld`

This runs the Java interpreter.  You should see the program output:

Hello, World!

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling to output java code to terminal these days. I finally found a way to do that. Following are my steps hope this is of some use to you.

1. Get the class path where your main method locates and switch to that directory. In my case, my main stays in

[image]
[image]

2. Set path of your jdk, for example
   **set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin**
3. Compile and run your code. Remember to include your package name. About package please have a look of this site: http://www.javatpoint.com/package

   In my case, my **main method** is in **Main.java**, and **Main.java** is included in package **sample**

You can do exactly the same steps to get your output from cmd, command line console.

[image]
[image]